Google Drive API returns null intermittently for files().list() on the App created folder using Kotlin
I am using Google Drive API but retrieving the Files/Folder list has being elusive.
I have many problems but I am addressing one of them in this post.
I have created a folder using the API in my App in Kotlin(Android API 34) and it is created successfully, I know because I connect to the Google Drive Web site and it is listed, also I can upload and download files in the same folder. Then later I need to verify the Folder exists in the Drive. In order to do that I try to retrieve the Folders list but returns null in a intermittent way. Many times it returns null but some times returns the expected values.
Here is the Gradle library I am using:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

Here are the Manifest permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

As per request this the code to create the mDriveService:
val googleDriveService =
                Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    GsonFactory(),
                    credential
                )
                    .setApplicationName("House Inventory") 
                    .build()

            // The DriveServiceHelper encapsulates all REST API and SAF functionality.
            // Its instantiation is required before handling any onClick actions.
            mDriveServiceHelper = GoogleDriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService)

Class GoogleDriveServiceHelper top code lines where mDriveService is created:
class GoogleDriveServiceHelper(driveService: Drive) {
private val mDriveService: Drive = driveService

private val FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
private val FOLDER_NAME = "Inventory_Backup"
private val FILE_MIME_TYPE = "application/zip"
var FILE_NAME = ""

The following code is used to create the folder:
private val FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
private val FOLDER_NAME = "Inventory_Backup"

fun createFolder(): Task<String> {
    val tcs = TaskCompletionSource<String>()
    val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
    val metadata = File()
        .setParents(listOf("root"))
        .setMimeType(FOLDER_MIME_TYPE)
        .setName(FOLDER_NAME)

    service.execute {
        val googleFolder: File?
        try {
            googleFolder = mDriveService.files().create(metadata).execute()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw IOException("Null result when requesting Folder creation.")
        }
        val finalResult = googleFolder.id
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            tcs.setResult(finalResult)
        }, 1000)
    }

    return tcs.task
    }

The following code is used to verify the Folder exist:
val isFolderPresent: Task<String>
    get() = getFolderPresent()

    fun getFolderPresent(): Task<String> {
    val tcs = TaskCompletionSource<String>()
    val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

    service.execute {
        var result: FileList? = null
        try {
            result = mDriveService.files().list()
                .setQ("mimeType='$FOLDER_MIME_TYPE' and trashed=false")
                .execute()
            ////Here the result is null
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        var finalResult = ""

        if (result != null)
            for (file in result.files) {
                if (file.name == FOLDER_NAME) finalResult = file.id
            }

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            tcs.setResult(finalResult)
        }, 1000)
    }
    return tcs.task
}


As per Andrew's question I made some code modifications.
To make sure the Tasks are finished I rearrange the code sequence (for example):
mDriveServiceHelper!!.isFolderPresent
                .addOnSuccessListener { id: String ->
                    folderId = id
                    if (folderId.isNotEmpty()) {
                        //awake getFolder
                        mDriveServiceHelper!!.getFolderAccess(folderId)
                            .addOnSuccessListener { result: Boolean ->
                                if (result) {
                                    mDriveServiceHelper!!.getFolderFileList

                                    //enable other button as sign-in complete
                                    signInButton!!.isEnabled = false
                                    createFolderButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                    folderFilesButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                    uploadFileButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                    signOutButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                } else {
                                    signInButton!!.isEnabled = false
                                    signOutButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                    createFolderButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                }
                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception? ->
                                Log.e(
                                    GoogleDriveServiceHelper.TAG,
                                    "Couldn't get permissions.",
                                    exception
                                )
                                signInButton!!.isEnabled = false
                                signOutButton!!.isEnabled = true
                                createFolderButton!!.isEnabled = true
                            }

                    } else {
                        signInButton!!.isEnabled = false
                        signOutButton!!.isEnabled = true
                        createFolderButton!!.isEnabled = true
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception? ->
                    Log.e(
                        GoogleDriveServiceHelper.TAG,
                        "Couldn't create file.",
                        exception
                    )
                    signInButton!!.isEnabled = false
                    signOutButton!!.isEnabled = true
                    createFolderButton!!.isEnabled = true
                }

I moved all the code inside the [addOnSuccessListener] segments. That way anything that is dependent of the Tasks completions will wait for it before doing anything.
So far the Tasks are returning the data correctly.

You seem to be using a version from 2018?
Cross-reference v3-rev136-1.25.0 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive
Try the latest v3-rev20240521-2.0.0
But if it is not that:

Just so I understand the issue you correctly, you are certainly leaving enough time for the folder to be created?  As I see that you are using a ThreadExecutor and so if you executed createFolder() and immediately isFolderPresent() the task may not be complete.
Secondly, you know that the files listing endpoint paginates, so you may need to think about that if you will exceed the default page size
How do you create mDriveService?


To answer Andrew questions. The folder is indeed created successfully. I can confirm it by looking at Google Drive directly. I notice looking on other Users Topic Questions the situation about multiple pages but that I will address after I have made the basic stuff. I added more code in the Topic to answer the 3 question

And what about just trying a library upgrade, in case there was simply a bug i that 6  year old software?

I am going to do the library upgrade. I will have to test it some time to make sure it does the trick.
